# Payment option disappears when changing address during checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment

I have a very strange issue with my checkout page. When I order something and don't change the address or anything I get all my payment options like this:

[image]

But when I go a two steps back, and change the shipping address to anything different and then go back to my payment options, it looks like this:

[image]

The afterpay option is gone.

What could be causing that? There is no option that is related to this in my backend so it must be a bug of some sort. I am running magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the address you are using. There may be options available in magento backend that certain payment methods should be available only for this country.

Check whether there is an option for your payment method like this. This is one of the reason so far I encountered in PayPal payment

Regards,
Mithun Chakravarthi